# Form::model for One-to-one Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a User model that has a one-to-one relationship with a Writer model.

I'm trying to use `Form::model($user, ['route' => 'some-route'])` to populate the form with values from both User and Writer model but I only see values from the User model (since that's what I passed as argument in `Form::model()`).

I wish I could do `Form::text('writer.something')` but can't. Are there other ways to achieve it? Or it's a bad idea to do it that way?

Regards.

Comment: Interesting idea but I don't think it's currently possible using the Form Builder. I won't say it's a bad idea because your use case might be perfectly legitimate.

Comment: @JasonLewis Thanks for commenting. I was able to do it by removing condition from the FormBuilder library (the one that checks whether a model property exists) and adding something in the object_get method but It's not a healthy approach, my text input would have a name of 'writer.something' so I discarded it and just created the form manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is feature not implemented in Laravel 4.0.0

I hope it gets implemented in future updates. :)